# How to convert a keypair to a wallet type?

Tags: transactions, wallet, signature, send-transaction, node.js

I want to convert a keypair into a wallet type, So I can use that wallet to sign transactions on backend(Nodejs). How to do this ?

Comment: @C.OG it does .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `NodeWallet`

```
import NodeWallet from '@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/nodewallet'

..

const keypair = anchor.web3.keypair.generate()
const user = new NodeWallet(keypair)

// anchor 
const provider = new anchor.AnchorProvider(connection, user, {
    commitment: 'processed',
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @vicyyn what I did was this, 

[link]https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1864/how-to-bypass-wallet-approval-and-use-the-keypair-on-backend